# Múltiplos "form-controls" dentro de um mesmo "form-group"

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Nesta [seção](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/#basic-example) da documentação do Bootstrap 4, diz:

> "We do not support multiple form-controls in a single input group"

Mas na mesma página, na seção [Multiple inputs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/#multiple-inputs), um pouco mais abaixo, ele dá um exemplo usando múltiplos `form-controls` dentro do mesmo `form-group` e diz que são "visualmente suportados".

Não entendi muito bem, afinal devo ou não devo usar múltiplos `form-controls` dentro de um mesmo `form-group`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thiago o Bootstrap tem uma série de classes de validação de `form`, vc pode consulta-las aqui https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#validation e é a essas classes de validação que esse texto da documentação se refere

Nessa imagem vc pode ver as classes e métodos de validação, porem eles só são suportados se seguirem as regras, um `form-control` para um `form-group`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**E veja o que diz a documentação oficial do próprio BS:**

> While multiple `<input>`s are supported visually, **validation styles** are only available for input groups with a single `<input>`.

Traduzindo: *"Embora vários `<input>`s sejam suportados visualmente, **os estilos de validação** estão disponíveis apenas para grupos de entrada com uma única entrada `<input>`"*.

**Ou seja, as classes para estilizar a validação dos `forms` só funciona caso tenha um único `form-control` dentro do `form-group`, se tiver mais de um as classes não vão ser aplicadas.**